# Write-streaming to Google Cloud Storage in Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, azure-storage

I am trying to migrate an `AWS Lambda` function written in `Python` to CF that

1. unzips on-the-fly and read line-by-line
2. performs some light transformations on each line
3. write output (a line at a time or chunks) uncompressed to GCS

The output is > 2GB - but slightly less than 3GB so it fits in `Lambda`, *just*.

Well, it seems impossible or way more involved in `GCP`:

- uncompressed cannot fit in memory or `/tmp` - limited to 2048MB as of writing this - so Python Client lib `upload_from_file` (or `_filename`) cannot be used
- there is [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) official paper but to my surprise, it's referring to `boto`, a library initially designed for `AWS S3`, and a quite outdated one since `boto3` is out for some time. No genuine `GCP` method to stream write or read
- Node.js has a simple `createWriteStream()` - nice article [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-storage-exploder-221c5b4d219c) btw - but no equivalent one-liner in Python
- [Resumable media upload](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html) sounds like it but lot of code for something handled in Node much easier
- AppEngine had [cloudstorage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/blobstore/gcs/main.py) but not available outside of it - and obsolete
- little to no example out there on a working wrapper for writing text/plain data line-by-line as if `GCS` was a local filesystem. This is not limited to `Cloud Functions` and a lacking feature of the Python Client library, but it is more acute in CF due the resource constraints. Btw, I was part of a [discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3903) to add a writeable IOBase function but it had no traction.
- obviously using a VM or `DataFlow` are out of question for the task at hand.

In my mind, stream (or stream-like) reading/writing from cloud-based storage should even be included in the Python standard library.

As recommended back then, one can still use [GCSFS](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which behind the scenes commits the upload in chunks for you while you are writing stuff to a FileObj.
The same team wrote `s3fs`. I don't know for Azure.

AFAIC, I will stick to `AWS Lambda` as the output can fit in memory - for now - but multipart upload is the way to go to support any output size with a minimum of memory.

Thoughts or alternatives ?

Comment: upload_from_file uses a file-like object so maybe you can use a generator to do the work you want?

Comment: Unfortunately it requires the file handler to be open in read-only mode, not mixed (read/write). In other words, the file must exist in its entirety already. The goal is to read (to write the GCS/S3) as your write to the handler in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got confused with `multipart` vs. `resumable` upload. The latter is what you need for "streaming" - it's actually more like uploading chunks of a buffered stream.

`Multipart` upload is to load data and custom metadata at once, in the same API call.

While I like [GCSFS](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) very much - [Martin](https://github.com/martindurant), his main contributor is very responsive -, I recently found [an alternative](https://dev.to/sethmichaellarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h) that uses the [`google-resumable-media`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-resumable-media-python) library.

`GCSFS` is built upon the core http API whereas Seth's solution uses a low-level library maintained by Google, more in sync with API changes and which includes exponential backup. The latter is really a must for large/long stream as connection may drop, even within `GCP` - we faced the issue with `GCF`.

On a closing note, I still believe that the [Google Cloud Library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html) is the right place to add stream-like functionality, with basic `write` and `read`. It has the [core code already](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/34f97881096bf76faacda9908fb87384f6b9ee52/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L903).

If you too are interested in that feature in the core lib, thumbs up the issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3903) - assuming priority is based thereon.

Answer (score 4):

[smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) now has support for GCS and also has support for on the fly decompression.

```
import lzma
from smart_open import open, register_compressor

def _handle_xz(file_obj, mode):
    return lzma.LZMAFile(filename=file_obj, mode=mode, format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ)

register_compressor('.xz', _handle_xz)

# stream from GCS
with open('gs://my_bucket/my_file.txt.xz') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print(line)

# stream content *into* GCS (write mode):
with open('gs://my_bucket/my_file.txt.xz', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(b'hello world')
```