# Scrape page using Cloud Functions in GCP and load it to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have got question about GCP. Is it possible to **scrape** page on a daily basis using Cloud Functions and send it to BigQuery. I have already wrote working code in Python that **scrapes** page and save it to csv and now I would like to move it to cloud. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your scraped (`csv`) data to Google Cloud Storage from python. Bigquery supports loading data as a new table or appending new data to a table. The latter requires you to do it in python, the former can be done using the UI in the cloud console.

More info
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)
[And Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068947/write-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-in-python)

Comment: don't hesitate to add some pointer to the documentation to transform your correct answer into great answer!